# Plotando circulos em diferentes planos

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, plot

Eu necessito plotar circulos nos planos zy e zx, mas só consigo no plano xy, pois ao trocar de lugar as variaveis x, y e z, perdo o formato de corculo. Como posso consertar isso?

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d

theta = np.linspace(0, 2.*np.pi, 100)
phi = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 100)
theta, phi = np.meshgrid(theta, phi)
c, a = 1, 0.05
x = (c + a*np.cos(theta)) * np.cos(phi)
y = (c + a*np.cos(theta)) * np.sin(phi)
z = a * np.sin(theta)

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax1.set_zlim(-10,10)
ax1.plot_surface(x, y, z, color='b', edgecolors='b')
ax1.view_init(36, 26)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vc deve zerar a coordenada do eixo que não quer que apareça o circulo. Por exemplo, se vc deseja plotar o circulo no plano zy, então

`ax1.plot_surface(xzero, y, z, color='b', edgecolors='b')`

onde xzero é um vetor de zeros ([0,0,0,..]) com a mesma dimenssão de y e z.

A mesma coisa vc faz para os demais planos.

Comment: Deu certo, obrigada! agora só falta eu conseguir plotar na coordenada que eu determinar :)